# TeXshop dock behaviour

Tags: texshop

I am a long-time user of TeXShop (which I love). I recently upgraded to a new mac (iMac with M1 chip, running MacOS Monterey). I have noticed a minor change in behaviour, and would appreciate help pinpointing how to fix it.

The TeXShop icon is permanently in my dock. When I right click on the icon, I see a popup with a list of recent files and some other choices. I believe this is maintained by MacOS and not by TeXShop. Previously when I clicked on one of the recent files in the popup, it opened in TeXShop. This is not happening any more. Is this a known issue? Does anyone have a fix?

Thanks

Comment: I've been using TeXShop (and Macs) forever and didn't know of this functionality. But it works for me (OS 12.4) (Intel, but it's unlikely this is a chip difference.).  You might actually have better luck asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com since this is indeed a system dependent functionality.

Comment: When you say "not happening" what actually happens? Does the file open with something else? Does literally nothing happen?  Does the list of files appear or are there no files? If the latter, then maybe your system preferences -> general  has set it to 0.

Comment: Nothing at all happens. I click on the file I want to reopen. Previously that file would have opened; now nothing whatsoever appears to happen. (However if I do something similar with MSWord (also in my dock), I am able to reopen recently closed files)